# SQL queries in a PHP loop fails after n-th iteration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

Gus,

I have a code that basically copies a bunch of records in one db and copies it to another. I need to do this for many records, so I have built an array with the variables that amend the query each time. Here is the structure of my array:

```
$array = [
["Brent_Chart_1", $List_Brent_Chart_1],
["Brent_Chart_2", $List_Brent_Chart_2],
["Brent_Chart_3", $List_Brent_Chart_3],
  et..... ]
```

And here is the loop that goes through the array and performs the SQL queries:

```
foreach ($array as list($a, $b)) {
     $queryx = "
UPDATE `meetings_ss`
SET `".$a."`= (
    SELECT `Data`
    FROM `charts`
    WHERE `ID` = ".$b."
    )
ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1;";

 mysql_query($queryx);
}
```

The problem is as follows: for some reason the first nine records are copied as expected and then nothing gets copied from the tenth. I know there is no issue with variable names, etc, as if I start the loop from the tenth record I get the same problem: first nine are copied but then fails on the tenth.

This leads me to think this is a memory issue, or perhaps this is not the proper way to handle multiple SQL queries? Can anyone suggest a reason as to why this is failing?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: How many rows are there in your $array?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message. There are 77 rows.

Comment: Your order by and limit is out if the subquery..

Comment: Did you try to print to resulting query and then run it manually with a sql client?

Comment: Yes -also, the error is replicated when I start on the ninth value. The query always fails on the ninth iteration, no matter where I start. Is this a memory issue? Do I need to release memory of some kind??

Comment: You have no WHERE clause at all. That query would just seem to try to update the row with the highest id continuously (77 times), updating a different column each time. When the update fails is it giving an error message (ie, try `mysql_query($queryx) or die(mysql_error());` )

Comment: Hello kickstart, that is correct, I am trying to update different columns of the last row

Comment: Guys, I don't think this is due to a syntax issue or any of the variables being wrong, etc. When I tried to replicate the query with a SQL client, this is what I get: `#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with the code. The issue is with the DB structure and the consecutive SQL queries eventually breaching the row size:

```
#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order by and limit is out of the subquery.. update clause can't have "order" or "limit" :)

Try changing your code like:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  $queryx = 'UPDATE meetings_ss SET 
      ' . $row[0] . ' = (SELECT Data FROM charts
    WHERE ID = ' . $row[1] . ' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)';

  mysql_query($queryx);
}
```

Comment: Hello Hardy, I have implemented your change and exactly the same problem is repeated. It fails after the ninth query and no longer copies records as expected.

Comment: Ok, you actually don't even need that order by or LIMIT there.. I'm 100% sure your problem is caused by your data. Put PHP error logging and viewing on and check the error.. or debug all the SQL clauses generated before executing them.

Comment: Hardy, is there a limit to the number of loops you can do with SQL queries? I don't think there is anything wrong with the data, as mentioned I tested this from different rows in the array, and it always fails after the ninth... I am stumped :-(